# Processor details in Windows XP

Tags: windows, cpu

I am using Windows XP - SP2. How can I check how many processors are available in my system and how many cores in each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) to identify your processor information

Comment: Yep, CPU-Z is a great tiny tool with lots of information.

Answer (score 4):

From the command line you can use WMIC:

```
> wmic cpu get numberofcores,numberoflogicalprocessors
NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors
2              2
```

For a multi-processor setup you should get one result line per CPU.

Comment: To return the number of physical processors along with the number of cores:

`wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors,numberoflogicalprocessors`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the new tool [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), by Piriform (the guys who made CCleaner).

Comment: +1 : it's a "new-kid-on-the-block" but it works fine and looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have [Powershell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) downloaded, you can execute the following.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class “Win32_Processor” -Namespace “root\CIMV2″ | Get-Member
```

Then look at NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors values. It uses [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) just as Joey's does, but you have more options in what you do with the info over the Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line (WMIC). For example you can add

`| tee C:\cpuInfo.txt`

More info about Powershell and WMI can be [found here](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-scripting-with-wmi/)